# Repeated query on related table are very slow. How to adjust schema to be efficient?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, caching, database-design

I have two related tables on in a postgres DB.  Let's say the first table is Products and the second is Transactions.  I have a search feature that queries Products based on specific attributes, some of which are dependent on Transactions (such as last sale price of a specific product).

My problem is that the search query often has to query Transactions for the most recent transaction every time it is searched which takes a long time.  It is noteworthy that Transasctions will be updated monthly or quarterly with the latest data.

My simple mind thought a solution would be to add fields for the most recent sale price, etc. in the Products table and run the query so that Products has a most_recent_sales_price field which is updated via query whenever the Transactions table is updated.  My gut is telling me that this is a hackey way of caching (which I know very little about). Is there a better approach for this?

Edit: there are approximately 1million transactions and 50,000 products in the DB.

Comment: Do you always just need data from the most recent transaction for the search attributes?  Also, can you provide some examples of how you are searching on the various attributes?

Comment: You're asking about queries and your schema. It would be helpful if you *showed us your schema and your queries*. Please also show `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for queries and your PostgreSQL version.

Comment: Another option would be to create table called something like `product_transactions_stats` with one row per product and your attributes (e.g. `most_recent_sales_price`). You can also consider creating [materialized view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html).

Comment: @steakchaser In a sense.  I have a couple different model methods which essentially query for the most recent transaction of a specific type, and return the value which is used as a variable in a calculation.  An example would be the user searching for products within a current profit margin range for a specified transaction type (e.g. Find products where Transaction.type = credit_card and Transaction.price / Product.unit_cost is over 30%.  The relevant Transaction.price/Product.unit_cost becomes the Product.current_margin)

Comment: @CraigRinger Will add schema and results.  The queries are run through the Rails app, so I'll try to figure out how to run that command for you.

Comment: @TomasGreif Your idea sounds like a fairly lightweight approach.  Thanks for introducing materialized views - seems like that should be my default approach for this unless I find a better way.

Comment: I'd stray away from using the most_recent_sales_price field. Instead I'd put an index on the updated_at field in the Transactions schema so that it can do a O(logn) (depending on the DB and index implementation) lookup to find the most recent transaction.